# Maven Release Plugin error

Tags: maven

I have a question on using maven release plugin in Jenkins. I am getting the following error:

`Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.1:prepare (default-cli) on project  You don't have a SNAPSHOT project in the reactor projects list. -> [Help 1]`

Can someone point me out what would be the issue?

Here is my project pom.xml structure

Parent pom.xml

```
<parent>
   <groupId>org.company.parent</groupId>
   <artifactId>comany-parent</artifactId>
   <version>0.2</version>
   </parent>

   <groupId>org.company.test</groupId>
   <artifactId>my Parent Project</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>Parent</name>
```

child1 pom.xml

```
  <parent>
      <groupId>org.company.test</groupId>
      <artifactId>my Parent Project</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
   <artifactId>child1</artifactId>
   <name>child-one</name>
```

child2 pom.xml

```
<parent>
 <groupId>org.company.test</groupId>
 <artifactId>my Parent Project</artifactId>
 <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 </parent>
 <artifactId>child2</artifactId>
 <name>child-two</name>
```

Comment: This means you have a pom module/child which does not contain a `-SNAPSHOT` version...

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. The below is my project pom file structure. can you point me out what is the mistake I am making here.

Comment: Hi, I have added my pom.xml file structure. Can you look at it and point me out what I am missing.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Does your parent pom has entries like `<module>...</module>` ? Furthermore how and from have you called maven to start a release ? Can you please add the exact call you have used? Furthermore have you used it from plain command line?

Comment: yes. I do have Modules  in my parent pom and mentioned my child module in that.

Comment: yes. I do have Modules  in my parent pom and mentioned my child module in that.  My task is to perform the release through Jenkins. I tried it in my local as well Jenkins too. both gives the same error

Comment: How have you called Maven to do the release? Can you make an example project on github etc. to show how your project really looks like?